# Decimal in for python

Tags: python, decimal, increment

I have to evaluate a function (3x-2) in a interval [-10,10] with precision increments from 1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, etc.
I tried this

```
a=1.0
for x in range(1,40):
    for y in range(-10,10,a):
        c=3(x)-2
        print(c)
    a=a/10
```

(The first for is because I need to get 40 decimals)
But I got this error

```
for x in range(-10,10,a):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are overthinking the problem. Here is a much simpler approach using `numpy` and `matplotlib` to visualize the answer:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

desired_increment = 0.1
upper_bound = 10
lower_bound = -10
pts = int((upper_bound - lower_bound)/desired_increment + 1)

x = np.linspace(lower_bound, upper_bound, pts)

y = 3*x-2

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x,y,'*')
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can use `np.linspace()` to change the size of the increments that you mention.

Comment: It worked, thanks.
But I have a problem, I can't reach more that 8 or 10 decimals with this, do you know another way to reach to 40? and the intervals are in 2 instead of 1

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 40 decimals. See my edit for achieving your desired increment.

Comment: I need to increment by 1, then by 0.1, then by 0.01, then by 0.001, and so on until 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000001 but with np.linspace() I can't reach more than 0.000000001
Do you know another alternative to reach this?

Comment: Why on Earth would you need 40th decimal precision....

Comment: I need to calculate the time that takes in every decimal precision and graph it (Homework stuff haha)

Comment: @RembrandtSánchezDosal how did you increment by `1, 0.1, 0.01` ?